# Firefox shows webcam permission popup everytime over secured origin https on mobile

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, webcam, getusermedia

In my javascript project, I'm calling getUserMedia to check whether the camera is connected or not after every 20 seconds. It shows me permission popup every time over secured origin on mobile. How to hide permission popup every time?

Answer (score 0):

gUM isn't really suitable for a capability probe (is the camera available?).

If you want to find out if any camera is connected, you can use enumerateDevices(). That won't tell you much about the devices unless your user has already allowed access, but it will tell you if they are present.

Why is this permission stuff so rigid? Because cybercreeps.